# What is a proper way to make locale in unified way from different representations?

Tags: java, locale

I have list with languages and locales, and I need to get string representations of all of these items in [IETF BCP 47 language tag](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/IETF_language_tag) format. What is the proper way to do it in Java?

- es-MX
- english
- en
- russian
- en-GB
- pt-PT

Comment: I fear you have a GIGO problem ;)

Comment: All of them are already in that format, except “english” (which should be “en”) and “russian” (which should be “ru”).